# Why was my spam flag disputed when another user's flag helpful?

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-answer, disputed-flags

Earlier I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23475401) ([screenshot for <10K users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCagP.png)) in the Low Quality review queue (it is now deleted so the review queue page I saw the answer in is the only way I can see it). I immediately identified it as spam, went to the original post and flagged it as such.

To my surprise a short while later my flag had been disputed *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*. I found this strange and told a friend who is also an avid flagger, (not yet known that he flagged the answer too).

When I get a spare moment I head to The Tavern linking the review page and asking why they think they flag was disputed (for personal development to flag correctly) to which I get an unanimous, yes that is spam. I tell my friend this and then he tells me he flagged the answer as spam too and his was marked as helpful.

Why was my original flag not marked as helpful when the second one on the answer was?

It could be possible that the third recommend deletion vote on the review cleared the flag but if that was the case then I wouldn't expect the dispute message I received.

Comment: If the review had anything to do with it, there should have been 6 recommend deletion reviews (or 3 delete votes from users > 20K) and then your flag would still be marked helpful. Only if 3 users had reviewed looks ok you would have had a decline due to the reviewers. So the involved mod probably missed that the user who posted that answer was a freelancer (based on what is in users profile) at the company that makes the advertised product. Even when I accept that sometimes a product recommendation is a good fit as an answer, for the question asked the particular product has no use.

Comment: I think the mod preferred a Not An Answer flag instead as you can only learn if the answer works if you follow the link. They might have wanted to prevent the spam penalty. If that reasoning is correct then we're welcoming  new user spam. What is strange is that they have earned the custodian tag for reviewing a suggested edit. That must have been on one of their own posts bit not the answer  discussed here. That might be a reason for the mod to not chose to honor the spam flag as spammers normally are not responsive to comments / edits / close votes etc.

Comment: @rene seems to be the case here... after one mod disputed it (presumably being not sure if it was a bad answer or genuine spam and missing the info. in the profile) - that user accumulated more spam flags on other (now deleted) posts, so when your friend flagged it shortly after, when another mod reviewed it, there was more signal to rule out good faith intentions

Comment: @JonClements To my knowledge the timeline of flags, is mine, my friends, first answer deleted, flags on other answers from the same user, then those deleted

Comment: @JonClements fair enough. Just for the record. I'm not involved here. I just happened to be in the tavern when this OP brought up their issue. And I wanted popcorn ...

Comment: That was on me. I was testing to see what happened when a rude or spam flag is declined. Sorry about that. I should have used a sock account to do that.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what happened with this flag:

Several posts were flagged for this account, but I reviewed them one at a time. The first one was link-only, 1 rep, not blatantly spammy (spam has more than links in answers most of the time, to promote the product even more). At first, it just appeared to me as a clumsy way to answer, specially the "If not, I believe the trial version is enough" part, which gives the impression you don't have to buy anything, and that poster doesn't know the product that much.

So I deleted it, marking the spam flag as helpful but giving OP the benefit of doubt at first by not bind-flagging the post.

But after that I saw that the same user posted more copies of the same answer. With such a low reputation, now it's becoming clear that it's spam, and I deleted the account, validating the other spam flags.

(well, maybe it wasn't *commercial* spam after all, poster has just pasted a link-only answer with a product in it 4 times if my memory is correct, but well, now the benefit of doubt has been reverted, and it is spam all right)

*Lesson learned*: next time I see a spam-flagged post which looks like a link-only answer, I'll check the user profile (like the person who flagged, probably, who can leave a comment explaining why it is spam, I'll read it and that will help me to decide too) before deleting it.

BUT the plot thickens...

The flag was still marked helpful, *but it was someone else flag* (the difference is that just deleting makes that it's not hidden from 10k users under the "rude or abusive" banner) so it's not disputed because of me. Checking the flagging history, it appears that *another moderator* cleared *your* spam flag and also accepted a "low quality" flag, while not deleting the answer. That's the real reason of your disputed flag.

[image]
2 users also incorrectly reviewed this post, in late answers & first posts queue. Oh dear...

*Lesson learned #2*: this R/A/spam flag status/resolution is complex. I should have checked flagging history before accusing myself :)

Comment: FYI. The *other moderator* came forward in comments on the Q.